# jquery form submit and textarea refresh

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need help with jQuery and ajax. need to load textarea content from file after submit.
can't figure out this. here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    #output {
        resize: none;
        width:100%;
        height:70%;
    }
    #time {
        background-color:#0F0;
    }
    #command {
        width:80%;
    }
    #submit {
        width:18%;
    }
  /*]]>*/
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var psconsole = $('#output');
                psconsole.scrollTop(
                psconsole[0].scrollHeight - psconsole.height());
            });

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#execute").validate({
                    debug: false,
                    rules: {
                        name: "required",
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                        email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        // do other stuff for a valid form
                        $.post('ajax.php', $("#execute").serialize(), function (data) {
                            $('#output').html(data);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });        
  //]]>
  </script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />

  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea readonly="readonly" cols="150" id="output">
<?php 
    echo $api->consoleOutput(50, 0); ?>
</textarea>

  <form action="" name="execute" method="post" id="console">
    <input type="text" id="command" name="command" /> <input type="submit" id="submit"
    value="si&Aring;&sup3;sti" /> <button id="button">siusti</button>
  </form><?php 
      $api->sendCommand($_POST['command'])
      ?>
</body>
</html>
```

all the other methods I have tried, the doesn't seem to help...
Stackoverflow rules for fast answers ;)

Comment: You need to include the plugin as well, usually it's named `jquery.validate.js`

Comment: Cheers, edited my answer as well then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form ID is "console", not "execute" so change this line:

```
$("#execute").validate({
```

To this:

```
$("#console").validate({
```

You *can* also select the form by its name, but can't see any advantage in this.

**Edit**: in order for all of this to work, you also have to reference the plugin itself, usually named `jquery.validate.js`.

Comment: @Justas If you add `alert(data);` inside the `$.post()` method, what do you see?

Comment: so could so tell me, how to make textarea refresh after submit?

Comment: @Justas see my comment on your question, looks like you don't have reference to the plugin thus `.validate()` can't really work.